# program only works half the time

Tags: pygame

for some reason this python program i saw on a youtube tutorial only works sometimes. Whenever i run the code, i get an error in the program telling me the program doesnt answer. But once in a while the code suddenly works perfectly.

```
import pygame, sys
from sys import exit

# crosshair class
class Crosshair(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, picture_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(picture_path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
            self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


# general setup
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))
pygame.display.set_caption('Runner')
background = pygame.image.load("sprites/graphics/bg.png")
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (800, 400))


pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

#crosshair
crosshair = Crosshair('sprites/graphics/crosshair.png')
crosshair_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
crosshair_group.add(crosshair)


# while loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit
            exit()


    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    crosshair_group.draw(screen)
    crosshair_group.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `pygame.quit()` instead of `pygame.quit`. Missing the parentheses means that you are not actually calling the function, and the window never closes.

You are getting a `not responding` message when you attempt to X out the window because `exit()` is being called, which ends your program, including the event-handling loop. The window is left with no program controlling it or making it respond to inputs such as closing, so you get that message.

Calling the `pygame.quit()` function will close the window right before the program quits, so it is all taken care of.